# How can I rotate my plane as per joystick rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, rotation, joystick

Currently I'm working on a shooter game its a 2d game built in 3d. I want to use joystick to control my player plane rotation. I have added my joystick on the canvas and with PointersEventData I'm handling my joystick rotation.
heres the code for it : (ControllerBG is outerCircle of Joystick & Controller is innerCircle of Joystick)

```cs
public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(controllerBG.rectTransform, eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2, 0, pos.y * 2);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        //move the joystick inner circle
        controller.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * (controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2),
                        inputVector.z * (controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2));
    }
}
```

now what I want is as the joystick rotate I want to rotate my player plane but I'm not getting how to do that please help me.

so far I have tried this but its not working for me :
1.

```cs
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(controller.rectTransform.anchoredPosition);
plane.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
    plane.transform.rotation,
    targetRotation,
    PlaneController.instance.steeringPower * Time.deltaTime);
```

2. created a function as well

```cs
private void Rotate(float dir)
{
    if (plane != null)
        plane.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * PlaneController.instance.steeringPower * dir * Time.deltaTime * 0.8f);
}
```

I have created this Rotate() but i'm not getting how can I use this on joystick motion i.e if controller(joystick) moves clockwise Rotate(1f) else if moves anticlockwise Rotate(-1f).

Please help me to solve my issue. Thank You in advance.

Comment: See this if can help. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1433049/rotate-object-to-joystick-direction.html. There are tons of links and tutorial on internet. You just need to google it.

Comment: Hey @SaadAnees, actually i did look for so much of tutorials online but I'm not getting solution how I want. can you please help me with this code I'll be really grateful to you

Comment: Sure. can you tell me which joystick control you want to add? Is it Mobile touch joystick?

Comment: yes its Mobile touch joystick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your `OnDrag` function as:

```
public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle
        (controllerBG.rectTransform,
        eventData.position,
        eventData.pressEventCamera,
        out pos))
        {
        pos.x = (pos.x / controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        float x = (controllerBG.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1) ? pos.x * 2 + 1 : pos.x * 2 - 1;
        float y = (controllerBG.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1) ? pos.y * 2 + 1 : pos.y * 2 - 1;
        inputVector = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;
        controller.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * (controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2),
                        inputVector.z * (controllerBG.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2));
        }
    }
```

I am assuming you have already implemented `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` for handling other events related to joystick. Im also assuming `inputVector` is a public variable to use it outside or you can use it in the same script. Its really upto you.

```
public Transform rot;
    void Update()
    {    
          Vector3 direction = new Vector3();
          direction = inputVector;
          rot.Rotate(direction);
    }
```

I hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: hey @SaadAnees, Yes i have already implemented code on OnPointerDown() & OnPointerUp(). I also understood the OnDrag() whatever changes you have made. can you explain the Update() part I didn't get you what you are doing.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I forgot to mention `public Transform rot;` which is your plane.

Comment: hey @saadAnees, I'm implementing this code in the same script file since I don't want to apply it in different script so what is that variableJoystick ? this is rotating so weird.

Comment: hey @SaadAnees, thank you so much I finally got the result how I want. you are really great thank you so much for helping me. I just change ```rot.Rotate(direction)``` to ```Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            plane.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(plane.transform.rotation, targetRotation, PlaneController.instance.steeringPower * Time.deltaTime);```

Comment: @AishaD.S. I edited the code. You can remove variableJoystick. It was my another joystick script name. You dont need that if your using the same script.

Comment: @AishaD.S. Glad I could help. Please vote up the answer if you can.

Comment: hey @SaadAnees, Sorry I don't have enough reputation score to vote up but I did accept your answer. Thanks alot again